# Raspberry pi - Run python on boot problem

Tags: python

I have a python script which runs every time the pi starts up, it moves a stepper motor for a timelapse camera. However for some reason it doesnt run the command in the PY script after the camera is moved which is

gphoto2 --trigger-capture
The log says "Unable to find camera attached" when it is clearly plugged in via usb, and the camera sees the USB connected. 
I get this error when its run either in crontab or rc.local or profile. I've tried all three.

However when running the command, just from the pi user "python stepper.py" it works fine? And takes a photo with that command etc??

Comment: maybe you should try having, say, a 20 second delay at the start of your script, to let the os fully boot?

Comment: @casper Round, did you fix the issue? I am having a similar problem